# How to connect electric door bell connection to Node MCU

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I have a electric door bell ( which is powered with Double AA batteries) , when the visitor presses it , it rings , plain simple .

I am thinking to remove the electric bell , and feed that input to ESP-8266 for digital input...

i want to understand what i would need to interface the input from button push to  ESP8266 pin

Comment: there are a lot of places on the web that teach you how to connect a switch to a microcontroller ..... i just finished posting wiring diagrams on how to connect a switch to a microcontroller here https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/84102/can-somebody-please-tell-me-how-to-wire-this/84103?noredirect=1#comment133781_84103

Comment: but i want to understand that the input from the switch is generating how much volts of input

Comment: are the batteries in the switch?

Comment: Is the doorbell itself a speaker driven by an IC? Does it "ring" as long as the button is held down? What exactly is the "bell" that you expect to remove?

Comment: @jsotola no batteries are installed in the electric bell..what i see in the existing connection is from the switch wire , the wire of electric bell is connected

Comment: @jonk yes doorbell is itself a speaker driven by 2 AA batteries....from what i see...a spring button is there outside gate , when it is pressed the doorbell rings , and when released , it doesnt... i want to remove the whole electric bell unit ...where a wire of switch is connected to bell...feed that switch wire to nodemcu , only concern here is i dont know how much current is coming from the switch so that i should not fry my nodemcu

Comment: @anshulkatta If you just remove everything, leaving only a switch, then it can be pretty easy. You'd be removing the batteries, too. There would be no need of them, if I understand "remove the whole electric bell unit." The main risk would be static electricity, lightning, stuff like that, since you would have a long wire running to an outside switch if this is a house. An apartment might be a much shorter wire and less risk. The worst that happens is you replace the nodemcu. But those are cheap. You will power the nodemcu with batteries?

Comment: no i ll power the nodemcu with usb power....i just asked my society electrician , he said the switch is powering 220v , that means i need to use relay....duh..i hate relays

Comment: `switch is powering 220v` .... what does this mean?

Comment: the rating coming from the switch is 220v , its a two way door bell switch